# Expected type-specifier before ';' token in Yacc

Tags: c++, bison, yacc

I am using yacc to parse one file and store records in `RAOperator` class object using yacc. 
I included the corresponding header file in yacc file and defined pointer to `RAOperator` object in %union directive in yacc file. But when compiling it is giving error
as follows:

```
exp.y:12:28: error: expected type-specifier before ‘;’ token
```

I am attaching yacc file where union is used with RAoperator class.

```
%{

#include "RA.h"
#include"y.tab.h"

%}

%union
{
char *strng;
vector<string>  *atr;
RAoperator* asdf;              // This is where error is shown
vector < vector <string> > *table;
}
```

This is RA.h file where RAoperator is defined.

```
class RAoperator
{
public:
vector< vector<string> > RArelation;
vector< vector<string> > RAattr;
};
```

I included all the necessary header files in RA.h file.

I have searched a lot for this error but couldn't find any solution.

Where I went wrong?

Comment: Where is the `line 14`? I have a suspicion it has to do with spaces in templates.

Comment: Sorry, it is line 12. I removed the comments before posting. Actually it is showing 28th column but there are only 22 columns in 12th line.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but you actually DO want us to count lines? In other words, can you point to the right line, please? With an arrow or something?.. Just in case, you do have `#include <vector>` somewhere, right? Because I think it's this line: `vector<string>  *atr;`. Still, can you, please, put a comment there saying `// <--- this is the offending line`?

Comment: Yes, I have included <vector>. I edited as you suggested.

Comment: So it does not see the declaration of `class RAoperator` for some reason...

Comment: Yes, but i don't know why. Can you specify that reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line where the error is indicated, is it possible that it actually says:

```
RAoperator* operator;
```

instead of `asdf`? (including the case where you have `#define asdf operator` or equivalent). `asdf` seems like an odd tag name; `operator` would be more logical, but it's a reserved word in C++ and would lead to exactly the error message you provide.

`"Expected type-specifier before ';' token"` is not an easy error to produce in gcc: this particular use of `operator` is one of the few cases I know of.

Comment: Thank you. But when I compiled with clang compiler the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with where yacc puts the `%{` ... `%}` code from the `.y` file.  It is included in the `.tab.c` file but NOT in the `.tab.h` file.  So if you have any other code that does `#include "y.tab.h"`, it needs to ALSO `#include "RA.h"` FIRST, or you'll get errors like this due to `RAoperator` not being defined (yet)

With bison, you can use `%code requires {` ... `}` to specify C code to be copied into BOTH the `.tab.c` and `.tab.h` files.

Comment: Chris, that's certainly a plausible theory, but it wouldn't cause compilation of y.tab.c to fail (since RA.h is included before y.tab.h) and it would trigger lots of other errors (vector and string not being defined, for example) but not "expected type-specifier before ';' token". The more likely error from a missing header on line 12 would be "'RAOperator' does not name a type". OTOH, changing `asdf` to `operator` produces precisely the error specified in the OP, although I don't know how to get it to specify an incorrect column offset in that error, so something else is going on.